# Java Servlets how to display the chinese Language in the result page?

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish-3

We have a data's in the database with chinese and english language. Using java servlets i want to display the chinese data's in the page.

using `SQL_JDBC_DRIVER` select the chinese value and display in the result page

```
while (rs.next()) {
            vendorname = rs.getString("vendorname_cn");                 
            }           

        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println(e2);
        }
        out.print(vendorname);
```

in the page its shows like `?????????`
Expected value(from database) : `郑其蔚`

let me know how can i display/print the exact  chinese language in the page

```
IDE: netbean
Server : GlassFish
```

Comment: Which encoding do you use for database storage, and which one is configured in the result page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed to set the content type, its working as expected once i set the content type.

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```